# Instragram api read comments without media id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Has anyone tried to fetch all comments across media objects given an access token/user id?

The published API expects a media-id :
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{mediaid}/comments?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No bulk comment API for Instagram. I don't think it would be supported as well. - it was there for FB graph API v1.0 and removed in v2.0 after. And now every Instagram API is being migrated to FB graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user
trend seem to favour that it won't be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  The subscription api does not seem to notify about comments added to a media asswell! The APIs are turning out to be less useful for any meaningful use.